# What is a good way to plot large volume of simple x,y,z data on CartoPy map?

Tags: python, geopandas, cartopy

I have a large dataset that is extracted from a `JSON` file and now sits in `numpy.array`s such as these:
`lat = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]`
`lon = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]`
`data = [0, 3, 1, 0, 0]` -- `data` ranges from 0-100

Its very simple but large. Basically there is a data value for each lat/lon pair, which is over 6000. I would like to plot this data on a `cartopy` map anyway that I can. I presume that plotting the data as bins at the lat/lon point and coloring based on the data value would be best.Perhaps after a gaussian filter to smooth the data.

Any ideas as to how to accomplish this?

I have tried creating python shapely geometry from the data initally but I ran into several problems.

Comment: In most cases, it is bad way to plot large volume of data on cartopy. Geographic data should be simplified and its attributes classified for effective cartographic rendering/visualization.

Answer (score 0):

the main problem is the overhead introduced from the creation of a very large number of shapely geometries which contain a lot of additional properties that you don't need if you only want to create a plot.

I'm the creator of [EOmaps](https://github.com/raphaelquast/EOmaps), a package that lives on top of matplotlib/cartopy and provides capabilities to visualize and analyze millions of datapoints with ease.

For example, here's how you would plot a raster of 2 million datapoints:

```
from eomaps import Maps
import numpy as np

x, y = np.linspace(-50, 30, 1000), np.linspace(-20, 50, 2000)
x, y = np.meshgrid(x, y)
z = x**2 + y**2

m = Maps()
m.add_feature.preset.coastline()
m.set_data(data=z, x=x, y=y, crs=4326)
m.set_shape.raster()
m.plot_map()
```

[image]

And here's how you could handle 1 million random datapoints via data-shading.

```
from eomaps import Maps
import numpy as np

x, y = np.random.normal(-50, 50, 1000000), np.random.normal(-50, 50, 1000000)
z = np.random.randint(0, 100, x.size)

m = Maps()
m.add_feature.preset.coastline()
m.add_feature.preset.ocean()
m.set_data(data=z, x=x, y=y, crs=4326)
m.set_shape.shade_points(aggregator="first")
m.plot_map(set_extent=False, cmap="viridis")
```

[image]